# If statement within a loop, result always returning True

Tags: python, if-statement

Edit: Thank you to everyone who answered the question, I now see what I was doing wrong and your explanations were all really helpful! (I wanted to upvote but I don't have enough reputation apparently). Also sorry, I was aware that other people had likely asked me question, I just couldn't find one, guess it's not knowing what to search for.

First post and I'm sorry if this is a very beginner error but I've been scratching my head over this all evening and can't for the life of me work out what the issue is.

I'm trying to run the below if statement within a double for loop which is iterating through a list and can't get it to return false. I've tried looking it up and thought it may be a data type comparison issue but I've double checked that (hence why everything is declared as an int) and it doesn't seem to be an issue. Everything is in integers so I'm sadly a bit lost!

Any help you can give would be most appreciated! Thankyou!

```
for search_site in range(len(search_list)):
    for product in range(len(product_list)):
        if search_site != int(1) or int(10) or int(13):
            print(search_site)
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
```

I've used the prints to see what's being compared and I generally get something like this (duplicates deleted for simplicity sake):

> 0
> True
> 1
> True
> 2
> True
> 3
> True
> 4
> True
> 5
> True
> 6
> True
> 7
> True
> 8
> True
> 9
> True
> 10
> True
> 11
> True
> 12
> True
> 13
> True

Comment: `if search_site != int(1) or int(10) or int(13)` is just wrong. Search SO for many duplicate posts.

Comment: what is the expected final result? do you need to iterate on the products list again and again for each search site ? Or your could iterate on both list simultaneously? and also you want to skip search site 1, 10 and 13, right?

Comment: also can you share the content of these 2 lists you iterate on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if search_site != int(1) or int(10) or int(13):
```

This doesn't mean what you think it means. It means

```
if (search_site != 1) or 10 or 13:
```

That is, the if statement is true if `search_site` is not equal to one, or if ten is not equal to zero, or if thirteen is not equal to zero. Consider

```
if search_site != 1 or search_site != 10 or search_site != 13:
```

or, more concisely,

```
if search_site not in [1, 10, 13]:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat the variable name for each 'or' part of the test. And here you probably wanted to use 'and' instead of 'or' otherwise if will always be true:

```
for search_site in range(len(search_list)):
    for product in range(len(product_list)):
        if search_site!=1 and search_site!=10 and search_site!=13:
        #if search_site not in [1, 10, 13]:
            print(search_site)
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

Already you could make the code easir to read like this:

**Refactor 1:** use `not in` + swap the test

```
for search_site in range(len(search_list)):
    for product in range(len(product_list)):
        if search_site in (1, 10, 13):
            print('False')
        else:
            print(search_site)
            print("True")
```

**Refactor 2:** use `enumerate` instead of `range` + `len`

```
for search_site_idx, _ in enumerate(search_list):
    for product_idx, _ in enumerate(product_list):
        if search_site_idx in (1, 10, 13):
            print('False')
        else:
            print(search_site_idx)
            print("True")
```